# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln(|p(e^{i\theta})|)\, d\theta$ using Mahler measure

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polynomials, definite-integrals

Let $p$ be a polynomial which can be factored over the complex numbers as $p(z) = a(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)\cdots(z-\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_n$ is a root of $p$.

The Malher measure of $p$ is defined as

$$M(p) = |a| \prod_{i=1}^n \max\{1,|\alpha_i|\}$$

Using Jensen's formula, we also get

$$M(p) = \exp\left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln(|p(e^{i\theta})|)\, d\theta \right)$$

The integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln(|p(e^{i\theta})|)\, d\theta$ came up in some fluid math I'm working out for a real-time fluid simulation.  Using Jensen's formula I can find the integral as a function of the roots of $p$, but calculating the roots of $p$ is relatively expensive.

Is there a way of finding the Mahler measure of a polynomial that doesn't involve finding the roots first?  From some Googling I found [Estimating Mahler measures using periodic points for
the doubling map](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdbl/mahler-27April.pdf), but the math is beyond me.  Alternatively maybe there's a better way of evaluating $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln(|p(e^{i\theta})|)\, d\theta$ without relying on Mahler measure at all?

Comment: Certain classes of polynomials have very regularly spaced zeros.  Asymptotic formula for the zeros are available in certain cases.  If you have a particularly polynomial set in mind, please share it, and maybe it will be possible to make some progress.

Comment: The coefficients come from a Fourier transform of some control points.  In general I don't expect them to have any particular form.  I can find the roots of an arbitrary polynomial by finding the eigenvalues of a companion matrix, but this is $O(n^2)$ at best.